# Multiple connection string in Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dapper

I have a Web API 2 using Dapper.net, and it's accessed by various client with their own database. Currently, I'm using custom header called `Client-Id` to identify the client.

This `Client-Id` contains a `ConnectionString` name and I passed this connection string into my constructor.

Here's my project structure:

> ```
> Api.Persentation -> Api.Service -> Api.Logic
> ```

The connection string will pass from `Api.Persentation` to `Api.Logic` as follows:

**Api.Persentation**

```
public string testApi()
{
//using the service
//consider the connection string was handled on base class
var _myService = new testApiService(base.ConnectionString); 

return _myService.HelloWorld();
}
```

**Api.Service**

```
public class testApiService: BaseService
{
    #region const
    //This class was from API.Logic
    private readonly testApiRepo _testApiRepo;

    //the connectionString passed into base class to use a log repo
    public testApiService(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        this._testApiRepo = new testApiRepo(connectionString);
    }
    #endregion


    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        //access API.Logic
        return this._testApiRepo.GetHelloWorld();
    }
}
```

**Api.Logic**

It has two classes, where `BaseConnection` is an abstract class to open the connection (the class how I use `ConnectionString`). The second one is, `testApiRepo` showing how I use the connection to get a database value.

```
/*-------------
BaseConnection Class
-------------*/
    public abstract class BaseConnection
    {
        private string _connectionString;
        public BaseConnection(string ConnectionString)
        {
            this._connectionString = ConnectionString;
        }

        public MyDbConnection GetOpenConnection(bool mars = false)
        {
            string cs = this._connectionString;
            if (mars)
            {
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder scsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cs);
                scsb.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
                cs = scsb.ConnectionString;
            }

            //Finally we use the connection string in here
            var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[this._connectionString].ToString());
            MyDbConnection DbConnection = new MyDbConnection(connection);
            DbConnection.Open();
            return DbConnection;
        }
    }

/*-------------
testApiRepo Class
-------------*/
    public class testApiRepo : BaseConnection
    {
        #region Const
        //the connection will handled on base class
        public CommissionRepo(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }
        #endregion

        public string GetHelloWorld()
        {
        //using base class to open connection
        using (var _db = base.GetOpenConnection())
        {
            string query = "SELECT 'HelloWorld'";
            var result = _db.Query<string>(query);
            return result.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Watch out for typos like "Persentation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I would highlight a **security problem**: you're directly exposing your implementation to service users. They just need to try different `Client-IDs` to connect to different databases. Connection string should be *deduced* by your application logic from client's authentication (whatever you use for this).

---

`testApi()` does not follow common .NET naming guidelines, method names should be Pascal case: `TestApi()` (also I would consider to use a little bit more descriptive name, `TestServiceConnection()`, maybe). The same apply for `testApiService` (`TestApiService`) and your local variable `_myService` (prefixes such as `_` are controversial but - when used - they denote member fields, not local variables or parameters).

Also classes `testApiService` and `testApiRepo` has same naming issue.

---

- `BaseConnection` is abstract, you'd better also declare its constructor as `protected`.
- `_connectionString` is initialized only in constructor then it should be marked as `readonly`.
- `ConnectionString` constructor parameter should be camel case: `connectionString`.

---

In `GetOpenConnection()` you're using a boolean flag `mars`, they should be used sparely because reading `GetOpenConnection(true)` you don't immediately understand what it means (`true`...what?) and whenever possible they should be replaced with enum or different methods. I'd also consider to do not have a default value: do you really call it so often you want to save those few characters?

---

Be careful when you create and return disposable objects, if something goes wrong creating `MyDbConnection` (again it should be `myDbConnection`, also better name is required) object then an exception is thrown and connection isn't immediately destroyed: when a SQL connection is popped from pool is an implementation detail you should not rely on.

---

All your classes are `public` and none of them are `sealed`. Will they be used outside assembly where you declared them? If not then they should not be `public`. Also `TestApiRepo` should be renamed and marked as `sealed`.

---

There isn't much more I can say about these snippets but I think you should change little bit your architecture. For example what you call `BaseConnection` in reality is not a connection! It's a factory class where you build connection objects (`MyDbConnection`) and `testApiRepo` has nothing to do with that factory (it should not be a derived class) but, instead, accept factory as parameter (or a connection string and then instantiate your `ConnectionFactory` class).

Comment: thank you for answer my question, it's good review. however I need to know about the way I passed `ConnectionString` name from my controller to `BaseConnection` class. Is it a good approach?

Comment: I don't see controller so I don't have much context but if you mean "pass connection name through a constructor parameter" then yes. Just remember to be careful it's a connection name (not a connection string) when mars is true and user is authorized to use it. If your factory caches anything shared between multiple requests/users then you may also consider to use a property (but I wouldn't start with something more complicate than necessary)

Comment: Also  check BCDOTWEB's answer, he highlighted other points I didn't see!

Comment: actually it's not a human readable I do an encryption on my `Client-Id` (*it's the header request on API to get connection name) and decrypt on my `MessageHandler`. also, I'm going to add autofac to my API soon and I new on implementing this. I read the documentation that it has to do with constructor. I wonder wheather my connection name would affect to Dependency Injection?

Comment: If you use autofac then don't worry, it supports parameters!

Comment: awesome, thank you for your time. i really appreciate your answer

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Adriano's remarks, some quick additional tips:

- Avoid `#region`, especially when it's a 20 line class.
- Comments should be used to communicate ***why*** something was implemented in that particular way. Ones like `//access API.Logic` or `//Finally we use the connection string in here` don't tell me anything the code isn't already saying.
- Naming is hard, I know, but `MyDbConnection` as a class name isn't useful. I have no idea what `mars` means.
- Avoid abbreviations like `cs`, just name it `connectionString`. (Same for `scsb`) Moreover, why is it even there? You don't do anything with `cs`.
- Unless I'm wrong, `_connectionString` doesn't contain a connectionString, but it contains its name.
- Code like `SqlConnectionStringBuilder scsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cs); scsb.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;` looks outdated to me. Why not simply write `var sqlConnectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cs) { MultipleActiveResultSets = true };`?
- Moreover, the whole "get the connection string" logic really belongs in a separate method instead of being part of `GetOpenConnection`.

Comment: thank you for your review, I'm really curious about the separate method you talking about. How should I transfer the connection string name to my `BaseConnection` class?